# Struggling with a proof in the preprint 'Hermitian geometry on resolvent set'

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have been struggling for awhile with a particular argument in the paper below. I posted the question first on MathSE, but I got no answers. I understand however that MO might be an overreach for this type of questions, so please close it if this is indeed the case.

Here is the preprint, by Douglas and Yang:

> Ronald G. Douglas, Rongwei Yang, *Hermitian geometry on resolvent set*, (2016), arXiv:[1608.05990](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05990).

Apparently only the first half of the preprint was published in

> Douglas R.G., Yang R, *Hermitian Geometry on Resolvent Set* (2018). In: André C., Bastos M., Karlovich A., Silbermann B., Zaballa I. (eds) Operator Theory, Operator Algebras, and Matrix Theory. Operator Theory: Advances and Applications, vol **267**. Birkhäuser, Cham. doi:[10.1007/978-3-319-72449-2_8](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-72449-2_8)

However, the theorem whose proof I do not entirely understand is quoted (the arXiv reference) in a subsequent paper by Liang and Yang.

I am having troubles with Theorem 7.1 in the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05990), more precisely the part where the authors show that (vector subspace) $M_{\tau}$ is closed. To briefly explain, if $V\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ is an operator for which $0$ is an isolated value of the spectrum, the authors define for every non-zero $x$:
$$
k_x:=\inf_{\delta}\sup_{|z|<\delta}\frac{\log||(z-V)^{-1}x||}{\log||(z-V)^{-1}||}
$$

Then they define 
$$
M_{\tau}:=\{x\in H: k_x\leq \tau\}\cup\{0\}
$$

Either I don't understand their proof, or it indeed has a gap. My issue is with the third line on page 43: "Taking limit when $\delta^{'}\to 0....$". I don't think they can do that and obtain what they claim, since $n$ in that inequality   depends on $\delta^{'}$, so it may change as $\delta'\to 0$. Is it something I am missing in their argument? Can it be fixed if it is indeed faulty?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I took the liberty of extending the title, since "struggling with a proof" together with "MathSE" could indicate something quite off-topic here. But I think the question is completely on-topic, and welcome to MO!

Comment: Indeed it seems it is a mistake. I tried to fix it....but I could not, nor could I construct a counterexample.